# Trigger mousemove and get the coordinates

Tags: jquery, mousemove, eventtrigger

I got this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/five0nine/qJJQW/64/)

```
$('#test').trigger('mousemove', [Handler],{type:'BLUE!'});
```

and I try to get the coordinates for the red square when I "mousemove" on the blue one through the trigger method.

Is that possible?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").on("mousemove", youCantHandleTheFunc);

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#test').trigger('mousemove', {
      type: 'custom mouse move'
    });
  });

  $('#test2').mousemove(function() {
    $('#test').trigger('mousemove', {
      type: 'BLUE!'
    });
  });
});

function youCantHandleTheFunc(e, customE) {
  if (customE != undefined) {
    e = customE;
  }
  $('#result').html(e.type);
  var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";

  $("span:first").text("( event.pageX, event.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#test2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>

<p>
  <button type='button' id='button'>touch me to trigger the mousemove event on the block</button>
</p>

<p id='result'></p>

<span>Move the mouse over the div.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting [`document.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) , [`MouseEvent.initMouseEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent) for [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)

> Although `.trigger()` simulates an event activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event.

```js
$(function() {
  
  function triggerMouseMove() {
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window);
    document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(e);
  }
  
  $("#test").on("mousemove", youCantHandleTheFunc);

  $('#button').click(function() {
     triggerMouseMove()
  });

  $('#test2').mousemove(youCantHandleTheFunc);


  function youCantHandleTheFunc(e, customE) {
    console.log(e, customE)
   // if (customE != undefined) {
   //   e = customE;
   // }
    $('#result').html(e.type);
    var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";

    $("span:first").text("( event.pageX, event.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
  }

})
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#test2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id='test'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>

<p>
  <button type='button' id='button'>touch me to trigger the mousemove event on the block</button>
</p>

<p id='result'></p>

<span>Move the mouse over the div.</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you break the code, don't you? The button don't works anymore and by the way it still show "undefined" for some "mousemove" on the blue square.

Comment: @rickozoe See updated post. Included `triggerMouseMove()` as example of how to return values to `#result` on `mousemouse` .

Comment: @rickozoe Perhaps not interpret Question correctly , here . What is requirement ?